# Last iteration overwrites previous properties in Object

Tags: javascript, geojson

I am trying to give individual ID's to some features in a (geo)json file.

```
Object.keys(hexgrid.features).forEach(function(key,i){
    hexgrid.features[key].properties.hexId = (i+1)
})

Object.values(hexgrid.features).forEach(function(feature){
    console.log(feature.properties.hexId)
})
```

Expected Output:

```
1
2
3
...
7790
```

Actual Output:

```
7790
7790
7790
7790
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just use `forEach` -> `hexgrid.features.forEach((v, i) => v.properties.hexId = i + 1)`

Comment: As written, your code does produce the expected output. https://jsfiddle.net/udwgh25b/  In your actual code, are you by any chance doing something asynchronous inside that loop?